# How to fill a ReadOnlyObservableCollection in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to define a view model instance as design data in xaml if it contains a property that's of type `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`?

When I use this

```
<viewModels:ProcedureEditorViewModel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                                 xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ExampleUser.GUI.ViewModels">
    <viewModels:ProcedureEditorViewModel.Procedures>
        <viewModels:ProcedureViewModel Name="Procedure A" />
        <viewModels:ProcedureViewModel Name="Procedure B" />
        <viewModels:ProcedureViewModel Name="Procedure C" />
    </viewModels:ProcedureEditorViewModel.Procedures>
</viewModels:ProcedureEditorViewModel>
```

as design data, the list of procedures is empty in the designer.
If I change the type of `Procedures` from `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` to `ObservableCollection` or even `IEnumerable`, I get to see my three design data procedures in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

The way which would definitely work would be to write your own markup extension of some sort.
By the time you did that, you might feel that just writing code to do this is easier.
Or just use a regular observablecollection.

XAML uses parameterless constructors. They never quite managed to implement xaml2009 and x:TypeArguments fully. As you read the documentation, you think "this is going to work"  then you get to the bit where it says it only works in "loose" uncompiled xaml  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/generics-in-xaml

You can actually merge an uncompiled resource dictionary. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28797.wpf-dynamic-xaml.aspx#Loading_a_Flat_File_as_a_Resource_Dictionary
  I've never tried x:TypeArguments with that but you could give it a go. Maybe it'll work.